# Better way to find $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}+\sqrt{4x^2+5x-6}}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to find $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}+\sqrt{4x^2+5x-6}}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

If I use l'Hospital, I get a $0$. Just want to clarify is the answer is $0$?

Is there any other way besides using l'Hospital?

We can factorise and get

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{(x+1)(x-3)}+\sqrt{(x+2)(4x-3)}}{x+\sqrt{(x-1)(x+1)}}$$

is factorising helpful in any way?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: i think should be 3/2

Comment: If you aren't sure what the answer is for something, WolframAlpha is a great tool:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+x--%3E+infinity+of+(+Sqrt%5Bx%5E2-2x%2B3%5D%2BSqrt%5B4x%5E2%2B5x-6%5D)%2F(+x+%2B+Sqrt%5Bx%5E2-1%5D+)

Comment: Have you tried multiplying both numerator and denominator by $x-\sqrt{x^2-1}$?

Comment: $9$ answers, what is the record ?

Comment: Just do the leading term analysis you would do for polynomials (if you want you can think of this as a polynomial with arbitrary exponents). (x^(2*1/2)+2x)/2x =3/2

Answer (score 4):

Hint : Didive denominator and numerator by $x$ and use $\frac{1}{x}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}}$

Answer (score 1):

Divide top and bottom by $x$, bringing it under the root you divide by $x^2$:

$$
\begin{split}
L &=
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}+\sqrt{4x^2+5x-6}}
                       {x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}\\
 &= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1-2/x+3/x^2}+\sqrt{4+5/x-6/x^2}}
                           {1+\sqrt{1-1/x^2}}
\end{split}
$$

What happens when you take the limit now?

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=1/x$,
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}+\sqrt{4x^2+5x-6}}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1-2t+3t^2}+\sqrt{4+5t-6t^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\frac{3}{2}.$$

P.S. Note that the limit is different at $-\infty$:
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}+\sqrt{4x^2+5x-6}}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}=-\infty.$$
The sign of $\infty$ is not specified in the original question.

Comment: no need for Taylor expansion, just plug in...

Comment: @gt6989b  Yes, you are right. It was much easier than I thought!!

Comment: No need to specify sign of $\infty$ just like there is no need to specify sign of $4.$

Answer (score 1):

Because terms in numerator and the denominator grow linearly as $x$ increases, we can cancel that:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{(x+1)(x-3)}+\sqrt{(x+2)(4x-3)}}{x+\sqrt{(x-1)(x+1)}} =  \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1-\frac{3}{x}\right)}+\sqrt{\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)\left(4-\frac{3}{x}\right)}}{1+\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}} \stackrel{u \to \frac{1}{x}}{=} \lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sqrt{\left(1+u\right)\left(1-3 u\right)}+\sqrt{\left(1+2 u\right)\left(4-3 u\right)}}{1+\sqrt{\left(1-u\right)\left(1+u\right)}} = \frac{1+2}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}+\sqrt{4x^2+5x-6}}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

Divide top and bottom by $x$ to get:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{3}{x^2}}+\sqrt{4+\frac{5}{x}-\frac{6}{x^2}}}{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}$$

Then it can be seen as $x$ gets bigger and bigger all the terms with $x$ in the denominator will approach zero and so the answer will become:

$$\frac{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{4}}{1+\sqrt{1}}=\frac{3}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}+\sqrt{4x^2+5x-6}}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}(\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}+\sqrt{4x^2+5x-6})}{\frac{1}{x}(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})}.$$ Thus we find

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{3}{x^2}}+\sqrt{4+\frac{5}{x}-\frac{6}{x^2}}}{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}= \frac{3}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Divide both the numerator and denominator by the highest power of $x$: note this is going to be the first power (since $\sqrt{x^2}$ gives a first power).
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}+\sqrt{4x^2+5x-6}}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}} &= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}+\sqrt{4x^2+5x-6})/x}{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})/x} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}/x+\sqrt{4x^2+5x-6}/x}{x/x+\sqrt{x^2-1}/x} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}/\sqrt{x^2}+\sqrt{4x^2+5x-6}/\sqrt{x^2}}{1+\sqrt{x^2-1}/\sqrt{x^2}} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{(x^2-2x+3)/x^2}+\sqrt{(4x^2+5x-6)/x^2}}{1+\sqrt{(x^2-1)/x^2}} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1-2/x+3/x^2}+\sqrt{4+5/x-6/x^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-1/x^2}}\text{.}
\end{align}$$
It isn't hard to see that the numerator limit is $3$, and the denominator limit is $2$ as $x \to \infty$, so we have $\dfrac{3}{2}$.

To see why, recall $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{x^n} = 0$ for $n > 0$, and thus $$\sqrt{1-2/x+3/x^2} \to \sqrt{1 - 0 + 0} = 1$$$$\sqrt{4+5/x-6/x^2} \to \sqrt{4+0-0} = 2$$$$1+\sqrt{1-1/x^2} \to 1 + \sqrt{1-0} = 2\text{.}$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $\frac{3}{2}$. Is very simple to prove this.

First you should note which terms on numerator and denominator are greater when $x \to \infty$, I mean, $\infty + 1$ is $\infty$, also $\infty^2$ is "greater" than $\infty$ and so on, but $5 \infty$ is as great as $\infty$.

In the numerator you have two square root. In the first the greates term is $x^2$ so $\sqrt{x^2}=x$, in th second the greatest term is $\sqrt{4x^2}=2x$, so you can add this terms because they are equaly big when $x\to \infty$ (terms with the same power are equaly big).
The same goes for the denominator so you have $2x$, and finally when you divide them you have $\frac{3x}{2x}=\frac{3}{2}$.

In this situations L'Hopital isn't very useful.

Comment: This is a good answer but be careful when you say $\sqrt{x^2} = x$.

Comment: you're right. It should be modulus, but because in this situation limit is for $+\infty$ it's ok :) ;)

Comment: That is true :)

Comment: Ah yes but how do you know what the other terms look like after taking the squareroot? How many terms are there? It makes sense that they would be less.

Comment: I don't care for the other terms inside the square root, because they are smaller. Only the "bigger/greater" terms have a significant contribution. As I said above terms with same power have same contribution. The greater power is $2$ inside the square root so that is wih contributes most and so on. This is like a thumb (but useful) rule. If you want a formal deduction you should devide everything by the greatets power and then take the limit (and you'll find out that it's exactly the same that I what I did)

Answer (score 0):

Using **Squeeze method**:

\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+2}+\sqrt{(2x+\frac54)^2-\frac{121}{16}}}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}\\
&\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x+(2x+\frac54)}{x+(x-1)}=\frac32
\end{align}

Also
\begin{align}
L&\ge\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(x-1)+2x}{x+x}=\frac32
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

By [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888732/a-question-about-substitute-equivalent-form-into-limit/1888764?noredirect=1#comment3872870_1888764):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}+\sqrt{4x^2+5x-6}}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}} =\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x-1+2(x+5/4)}{x+x}  = \frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: Addition is mutation of subtraction.