# A question about substitute equivalent form into limit: $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x^2+3x+1} = -1$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

When I had the calculus class about the limit, one of my classmate felt confused about this limit:

> $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x^2+3x+1} = -1$$

What he thought that since $x^2 > x$ and $x^2 > 3x$ when $x \to \infty$ so the first square root must be $x$ and same for the second. Hence, the limit must be $0$.

It is obviously problematic.

And what I thought is that make prefect square under the limit, though I know the right solution is to rationalize the numerator.

After perfect-squaring, $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}-\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2-\frac{5}{4}}$$ I assert that since there is a perfect square and a square root. As $x \to \infty$, the constant does not matter. So

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}-\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2-\frac{5}{4}}= \lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}-\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}\\ = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{2} = -1 $$

But when I conquer this limit: [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888153/better-way-to-find-lim-x-to-infty-frac-sqrtx2-2x3-sqrt4x25x-6x).

Here is my argument:

> $\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c} =O(\sqrt a(x+\frac{b}{2a}))$ when $x \to \infty$
>
> $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}+\sqrt{4x^2+5x-6}}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}} =\frac{x-1+2(x+5/4)}{x+x}  = \frac{3}{2}$$

Very concise get this answer but it gets downvoted.

I do not know what is wrong with my strategy. But in general case: for instance this problem about cubic root my strategy seems to work really efficient:

> $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt[3]{x^3+6x^2+9x+1}-\sqrt[3]{x^3+5x^2+x+1}$$

My solution is:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt[3]{x^3+bx^2+cx+d} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt[3]{\left(x+\frac{b}{3}\right)^3}$$

So the limit becomes: $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt[3]{(x+2)^3+O(x)}-\sqrt[3]{\left(x+\frac{5}{3}\right)^3 + O(x)} =\lim_{x\to \infty}  (x+2) -\left(x+\frac{5}{3}\right) = \frac{1}{3} $$

[This result gets verified by wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20%5B(x%5E3%2B6x%5E2%2B9x%2B1)%5E(1%2F3)-(x%5E3%2B5x%5E2%2Bx%2B1)%5E(1%2F3),%20x-%3Einfinity%5D).

To put all into a nutshell, what is wrong with my solution to these three problem. Is there any counterexample to this substitution. Any help, you will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong, it's only that the down voting person has wanted more rigor in the argument. You cannot write $O(n)$ just like that, it will need justification. Furthermore, to show that the limit actually exists, you should show that there is an upper bound to the sequence. I would not expect this in general, which means this solution is fine for me, but somebody else may be put off by the argument's slightly loose nature.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг How to generalize my statement and prove it is fine to the mathematics axioms or theorem about real anlysis. This is the key. By the way, I cannot generalize it. Could you help me? Write it in the full solution.

Comment: I will do that for the general case.

Comment: The problem with your classmate's approach to the first limit is that each individual square root tends to infinity, and he is in effect saying that $\infty-\infty=0$.  But you can **never** do arithmetic with $\infty$ in this way.

Comment: @David yes but what problem is in my solution?

Comment: @ZackNi As pDavid indicated, you are assuming "infinity minus infinity = 0$, which works out well because both radicals are square roots and the headcoefficients of the polynomials are both $1$. You can also get "infinity minus infinity=0$ from a squareroot and cuberoot, but using your approach will then yield to a wrong answer to the limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the general case $$A=\sqrt{x^2+ax+b}-\sqrt{x^2+cx+d}=x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac a x+\frac b {x^2}}-\sqrt{1+\frac c x+\frac d {x^2}}\right)$$ and use the fact that, for small $y$, using the generalized binomial theorem or Taylor series, $$\sqrt{1+y}=1+\frac{y}{2}-\frac{y^2}{8}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ For the first radical, replace $y$ by $\frac a x+\frac b {x^2}$ and by $\frac c x+\frac d {x^2}$ for the second radical. You then obtain $$A=x\left(1+\frac{a}{2
   x}+\frac{\frac{b}{2}-\frac{a^2}{8}}{x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)-\left(1+\frac{c}{2
   x}+\frac{\frac{d}{2}-\frac{c^2}{8}}{x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right)\right)$$ $$A=\frac{a-c}{2}+\frac{-a^2+4 b+c^2-4 d}{8 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Doing the same with $$B=\sqrt[3]{x^3+ax^2+bx+c}-\sqrt[3]{x^3+dx^2+ex+f}$$ and using $$\sqrt[3]{1+y}=1+\frac{y}{3}-\frac{y^2}{9}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ you should arrive to $$B=\frac{a-d}{3}+\frac{-a^2+3 b+d^2-3 e}{9 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
Doing the same with $$C=\sqrt[p]{x^p+a_1x^{p-1}+a_2x^{p-2}+\cdots}-\sqrt[p]{x^p+b_1x^{p-1}+b_2x^{p-2}+\cdots}$$ the limit will just be $$\frac{a_1-b_1} p$$

Your strategy works well for the limit because you just ignore the terms of  degrees lower than $p-1$.

Answer (score 2):

@ZackNi As David indicated, you are assuming "infinity minus infinity = 0,which works out well because both radicals are squareroots and the headcoefficients of the polynomials are both 1.You can also get"infinity minus infinity = 0 from a squareroot and cuberoot, but using your approach will then yield to a wrong answer to the limit. 
Generally, $\infty-\infty$ and $\infty*0$ situations should be converted into situations like $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ on which other techniques can be applied to get the desired limit. In your problem the conjugate approach is also a good way to go. (My comment post got messed up and I can't delete it...)

Comment: Yes I know that rationalize the numerator is the conjugate approach. But my approach always drive me to right answer so I really feel confused about what is wrong in my answer indeed.

Comment: @ZackNi That is because the nature of the problems are as such. Here is food for thought: To what line does $y=x\sqrt{1+4/x}$ approach when $x$ goes to infinity?. One can argue that the square root goes to $1$ for large $x$ and so the asymptote would be $y=x$. Alas, that is incorrect. Think about it...

Comment: do you know how to read critically. Here is my approach: $y = \sqrt{x^2+4x}  = \sqrt{x^2+4x+4 -4} = \sqrt{(x+2)^2 - 4} $ So when $x \to \infty$ ,$ y = x+2$. This is my solution!

Comment: Yes, the solution is correct, but the step after "so when ....." is algebraically not that elegant....

Comment: The answer by our Indian friend (which you accepted) is really a good answer. I hope you will post some more limit problems in the future of the nature I mentioned. The comment section is too small to go into all sorts of examples. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Let our problem be of the form $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{p(x)} - \sqrt[n]{q(x)}$, where $p$ and $q$ are $n$th degree monic(coefficient of $x^n$ is $1$) polynomials. First of all, without loss of generality, we will rewrite $p$ and $q$ in the forms:
$$
p = (x + a)^n + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_ix^i, q = (x + b)^n + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} b_ix^i
$$

where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are real constants which may be zero.(This we did in the cubic and quadratic case).

Now, note that $x+a \leq \sqrt[n]{(x + a)^n + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_ix^i} \leq \sqrt[n]{(x + a)^n} + \sqrt[n]{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_ix^i}$.Note that $$
\sqrt[n]{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_ix^i} \leq \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sqrt[n]{a_ix^i}
$$
However, the term on the left goes to $0$ as $x \to \infty$, because $i < n, $ so $x^i \to 0$. A similar logic follows for $q$. To complete the argument,

However, this is better expressed by: $x+a - ((x+b) + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sqrt[n]{a_ix^i}) \leq \sqrt[n]{p(x)} - \sqrt[n]{q(x)} \leq (x+a +\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sqrt[n]{a_ix^i}) -  (x+b))$.

On taking limits on both sides, we get $a-b$ on both sides, and using squeeze theorem, we get the result: $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{p(x)} - \sqrt[n]{q(x)} = a-b$.

Comment: Thanks a lot really excellent solution.

Comment: You are welcome, @ZackNi.

Comment: Good answer indeed +1

Comment: How can you apply the squeeze theorem when the limit is for $x\to\infty$? The left side converges to $-\infty$ while the right side converges to $+\infty$, there is no squeeze. -- More precisely, you are actually claiming that $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^i=0$.

Comment: How does the left  and right side converge to $-\infty$ and $+\infty$? Because $\frac{i}{n} < 1$, it follows that $x^{\frac{i}{n}} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: No, $x^a\to\infty$ for $a>0$, it is for $a<0$ that you get a limit $0$.